# Inset the X - and + buttons on a macOS window

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nstoolbar

In Electron, there is an option to make a window's `titleBarStyle` `hiddenInset`. (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window) Is there a native option to do this?

Chrome also does this, [image]

Comment: @Alexander the difference between my question and the linked one is, that I want the toolbar to be invisible, like in Discord's case.

Comment: Can you give a link to an example screen shot?

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot from Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
 - Add a toolbar to the window
 - Set the title to invisible and transparent
 - Remove the separator from the toolbar
 - Remove any default buttons from the toolbar
 - Disable toolbar customization